# Importing a nearly identical database into another

Tags: mysql

Sorry if this has been asked before I couldn't find an answer.

I have 2 databases, they are identical in structure except database 1 has a few extra columns.  The data in database 2 is a little more recent.

So:

Database 1 has a few extra columns in some of the tables.

Database 2 doesn't have these columns, but the data in the rest of the tables is more recent.

So I want to import the data in database 2 into database 1 overwriting the data in Database 1.  But I'd like to keep the existing extra columns in database 1 that do not exist in database 2.

Mysqldump obviously overwrites everything in database 1, that won't work.  There are too many tables and columns for me to know where the extra columns are in database1.  So I need a programmatic solution.

Thanks for any help or to point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the data in phpmyadmin, choose to export the data only, not the structure. Then you import that data into the database with more columns.

There are obviously limits to this. I assume that added columns are the only difference, that all non null columns have defaults and that the improved database has no data that needs to be kept.

This is about all advice we can give without knowing the exact table structure.

**Important advice**

In the future keep track of the modifications in SQL files that you can apply later to other copies of the database. It is in general easier to apply the changes (new columns) to a database, rather than copying data between two different databases.

These scripts are often called *migrations*.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [SQLYog](https://www.webyog.com/) that will do much of what you want.  It has the ability to diff and synchronise two different database schemas.  What I would be inclined to do is something like this:

- Dump database 1 and import into a new database 3.
- Dump database 3 and import into a new database 4.
- Use sqlyog to transition the database 3 schema over the top of database 4.  Fix any errors and repeat if necessary.
- Database 4 is now your new database with the schema from 1 and in theory most of the data from 2.  Look through it to see if that's what you want, otherwise scrap it, fix any problems and start again.